# Capturing Silverlight streaming

Tags: silverlight, video-capture

Does anybody know if there is an effective way to catch the streamed output of Silverlight and saving it to the Hard disk (in any format) without using screen capturing tools?

Comment: Might be a duplicate of "Capture specially encoded videos?" at http://superuser.com/questions/61864/capture-specially-encoded-videos

Comment: Not exactly, the problem there is apparently with the codecs. I don't have to manipulate AVI files, but capture streaming content and save it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're familiar with `.NET`/`IL Sourcecode`:

1. Locate the *Silverlight* `.xap` file and save it to your computer.
2. Change the extension from `.xap` to `.zip` and open it.
3. You'll find one or more `Dll`s. Take them, starting with the one looking like it's just for that *Silverlight* application. *(You can probably skip thirdparty ones.)*
4. Disassemble that `Dll` with [*IL DASM*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/f7dy01k1.aspx) or other `IL` disassembler tools.
5. Search for the source `Uri` of the video stream. Theoretically, it could be anywhere in the dump, look out in the main page's source. It will just look like a link to a media file, maybe `.asx`.
6. **You can not download it as a simple file. Remember it's a stream!** Use a program like [*VLC*](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) which is capable of saving and encoding a stream. *There you go.*

*Alternative:*

1. Start your favorite *Network Sniffer* (like [*Microsoft Network Monitor*](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=4865)).
2. Look out for the `HTTP` request which is followed by a massive flood of responses. **Thats the `Uri` for your stream.** *Continue with 6. in the first section.*

Comment: Where is the moov atom? I couldn't find it from the stream.