# download video from a website that uses silverlight to stream live stuff?

Tags: video-streaming, video-capture, silverlight

since it's silverlight, probably rtmpdump etc are out of the way (correct me if I am wrong.) There are tons of software to download flash, but it's silverlight... and live!

I am already aware about camstudio and such. I want to know if downloading is possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capturing Silverlight streaming](http://superuser.com/questions/62485/capturing-silverlight-streaming)

Comment: @techie007 ... I don't think any of the links are discussing live stuff.

Comment: I managed to open it in windows media player, what to do from that point on?