# Any Fraps alternatives out there?

Tags: screen-capture, screen-recorder

Are there any Fraps alternatives out there to record gameplay footage?

- **CamStudio** is out, since it's impossible to record gameplay footage with consistent and fluid fps
- **WeGame** records in very bad quality
- **Xfire** is out, since it only records in mono sound

So far I've listed perhaps the most widely used ones. Are there really no alternatives out there?

Comment: [Similar question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/392/how-can-i-record-demos-of-my-gameplay) on our sister site dedicated to gaming, for reference.

Comment: @NoCanDo: It would be helpful to know why Fraps isn't in the running.

Comment: @boot13: Uhm...because I'm looking for Fraps alternatives? I already have Fraps.

Comment: @NoCanDo: If we knew what it was about Fraps you don't like, we could avoid suggesting alternatives with the same characteristics.

Comment: That's precisely WHY I didn't list why I'm looking for Fraps alternatives. Because then y'all will be excluding software you think I might not like.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capture specially encoded videos?](http://superuser.com/questions/61864/capture-specially-encoded-videos)

Comment: Asking a question just for the sake of asking it is kind of useless. If a program does everything you want, why look for alternatives? What do you get out of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Open Broadcaster Software](http://obsproject.com/)

> Open Broadcaster Software is free and open source software for
>   recording and live streaming. Source code is available to everyone to
>   contribute and improve. Both 32 and 64 bit versions are available and
>   it's absolutely free!

Comment: This is by far the best alternative I've found. I can suggest it to everybody. Otherwise there's Dxtory.

Answer (score 1):

You may try the open-source [Taksi](http://taksi.sourceforge.net/) (attention: last release date is 2006):

> Taksi is a utility that allows you to
>   take screenshots and record video
>   clips of your favourite games and
>   other 3D-graphics applications.
>   Inspired by Fraps (www.fraps.com),
>   Taksi aims to provide an open source
>   alternative to that great tool.

Comment: Yea, I came across this. But like you said, its from 2006, and my programming skills aren't THAT good yet.

Comment: @NoCanDo: Try it. Google "Taksi video" gives 1,220,000 results!

Comment: @NoCanDo: You might also examine this list of alternatives : http://alternativeto.net/software/taksi/

Comment: I did, and like I said Taksi is old not mantained anymore. As for the other list, there's a few I'll check out.